# Расчёт времени до конца дня и года

Tags: php

Я сделал расчёт, у меня в браузере всё правильно работает, как и задумано. Я заметил, что со временем иногда, есть какие-то отклонение на +- несколько часов.
Какие у меня есть недочёты в коде?

```
$finish = explode('-',date('n-j-Y'));
$noon =  date('H:i:s j-n-Y', mktime(1, 0, 0, $finish[0], $finish[1] + 1, $finish[2])); //конец дня
$current = date('H:i:s j-n-Y', time()); //текущее время
$rest = strtotime($noon) - strtotime($current); //осталось столько секунд до следущего дня

setcookie('age', $num, time() + $rest);  //до конца текущего дня



$newYear =  date('H:i:s j-n-Y', mktime(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, $finish[2] + 1)); //конец года
$rest2 = strtotime($newYear) - strtotime($current);

setcookie('age', $num, time() + $rest2);  //до конца текущего года
```

Comment: Возможно связано с часовыми поясами? Например на сервере часовой пояс +2, а у вас +4

Comment: и как быть тогда?

Comment: Смотря, что вы хотите сделать. Если установить жизнь куки до конца текущих сток/года, Вам придется "дергать" время клиента (скорее всего через JS), и устанавливать время жизни

Comment: а почему не php?

Comment: Потому, что на прямую через PHP не получить время клиента или его часовую зону, могу ошибаться